# setup jwplayer 6 for RTMP stream with wowza

Tags: jwplayer, rtsp, rtmp, live-streaming, wowza

I am setting up Wowza Media Server to receive RTSP streams from Axis Q7401 video encoder and restream them to clients. I want to pull a single stream from the source (Axis Q7401 Video Encoder) and then restream multiple copies of that to multiple users using Wowza Media Server. I want the restreamed streams to be almost realtime or very small delay.

I followed this tutorial.
http://www.wowza.com/forums/content....e-streaming%29

Inside the camera.stream file, i used the following address

```
rtsp://username: password@[camera-ip-address]:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264
```

I opened the [install-dir]/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html and entered the following details for the stream.

```
Server: rtmp://[wowza-ip-address]/live
Stream: camera.stream
```

i want to setup jw player with wowza for viewing the stream.

I have downloaded jwplayer 6. Considering my above post, how do i setup jwplayer for camera.stream?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("player").setup({
sources: [{
file: "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/camera.stream"
}],
rtmp: {
bufferlength: 3
},
});
</script>
```

I am using the above code. JW Player is loaded but it gives me the message:

***Could not load plugins: File not found***

How do i access the stream in jw player?

What should be the correct path for the stream? I am using this **file: "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/camera.stream"**

Comment: That set up looks fine. Are you running this on your local C drive, or just on a local web server?

Comment: I have installed wowza in C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Media Server 3.6.3. And i am running the example from folder inside on the desktop jwplayer\ . I tried it from several different paths too. Ain't i using an absolute address? Why should the path matter?

Comment: Is there a way you can put something up that we can debug?

Answer (score 0):

Try below config:

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
   type: 'rtmp',
   streamer: 'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/_definst_/',
   file: camera.stream,
   rtmp: {
   bufferlength: 3
   }
});
```